# Custom Convolution in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

Lets assume i want to change the core of the Convolution, so that the kernel weigths change, based on the on the the incoming value in the middle of my kernel. How can i write such a layer in tensorflow ?

```
 Kernel -> Image  

|a b c|    |2 3 2|
|d e f| -> |5 4 5|
|g h i|    |5 3 1|

----> because e would be 4, if both were overlapping, the other wheigths should change like f(x):

f(x)=x*wheigt

|4a 4b 4c|
|4d e  4f|
|4g 4h 4i|
```

So atleast, change all wheigths out of the middle one like f(x).

Comment: How many input and output channels would you have, just one?

Comment: i want an RGB or HSV Image as Input, so 3 Channels, as Output i want also 3 Channels.

PS: The Basic idea is to calculate the Euclidean distance between the Pixels, with a convolution. But on top, the euclidean distance formular should be changed, based in the input value for the kernel (the middle weigth) as mentioned.

Comment: Ah I see, but would that be a normal convolution (so every pixel in each of the three output channels is a combination of pixels in the three input channels) or a separable one (so pixels of each output channel are computed from pixels in the corresponding input channel only)? I am asking because I think in the second case it would just be a separable convolution followed by an elementwise multiplication with the input...

Comment: It should be seperated like the following pseudocode example: **(1)** Take a Pixel of the Red Channel -->  Image[10,10,0] **(2)** compute the distances to all sourrounding pixels (3x3 conv, so 8 pixels). **(3)** Apply a function to the 8 distances, based on the value in  Image[10,10,0] --> (f(x)). **(4)** Output the new distance map for the red Channel. So i think it would be the second one, a seperable convolution, did that answer your question ?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, I think this does what you want (TF 2.x, but would be the same in 1.x):

```py
import tensorflow as tf

# Input data
kernel = tf.constant([[1., 2., 3.],
                      [4., 5., 6.],
                      [7., 8., 9.]], dtype=tf.float32)
img = tf.reshape(tf.range(90, dtype=tf.float32), [1, 5, 6, 3])
# Do separable convolution
kernel_t = tf.tile(kernel[:, :, tf.newaxis, tf.newaxis], [1, 1, 3, 1])
eye = tf.eye(3, 3, batch_shape=[1, 1])  # Pointwise filter does nothing
conv = tf.nn.separable_conv2d(img, kernel_t, eye, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
# Scale convolution result and subtract the scaling for the central value
result = conv * img - kernel[1, 1] * img * (img - 1)

# Check result
kernel_np = kernel.numpy()
img_np = img.numpy()
result_np = result.numpy()
# Coordinates of checked result
i, j, c = 3, 4, 1
# Image value
v = img_np[0, i, j, c]
# Image window aroud value
img_w = img_np[0, i - 1:i + 2, j - 1:j + 2, c]
# Kernel scaled by image value except at center
kernel_scaled = kernel_np * v
kernel_scaled[1, 1] = kernel_np[1, 1]
# Compute output value
val_test = (img_w * kernel_scaled).sum()
# Check against TF calculation
val_result = result_np[0, i, j, c]
print(val_test == val_result)
# True
```